# Can anybody help me out to open a link in new window / tab from pdf ?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have generated a html using wkhtml library and I have a href link in the pdf which should open in either new tab or new window. I have already gone over using window.open() , window.location.href , javascript function and also directly href. But these not works for me. May be I am not using as in proper way. Please this will be great to get answer from anyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get links in an embedded PDF to open in a new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228564/trying-to-get-links-in-an-embedded-pdf-to-open-in-a-new-window)?

Comment: in href use `target="_blank"`.

Comment: I have already used this but not working for me. I have to click the link in pdf file and the location after click should open in window. I dont have to open pdf file. I am firing click event in pdf file not in browser.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<a href="/link/to/pdf/file" target="_blank">Click here to view pdf in new tab</a>
```

`target="_blank"` attribute opens the specified link new tab

Comment: I have already used this but not working for me. I have to click the link in pdf file not in browser and the location after click should open in window. I dont have to open pdf file. I am firing click event in pdf file not in browser.