# How to connect PDF.js rendering signal to PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt5, pdf.js, qwebengineview

I use `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets` with `PDF.js` to display pdf files. Is it possible to connect the rendering state of the page to  the `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets`, so that another function is run, when rendering is complete?

**Edit:**

I tried different solutions, e.g. the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693207/how-to-know-if-pdf-js-has-finished-rendering). Unfortunately I can't find a solution how to connect the solutions described there with my `PyQt5.QWebEngineView`.

The way I tried: I added a new class function called `rendering_state` to my `QWebEngineView`. When the rendering is done (solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693207/how-to-know-if-pdf-js-has-finished-rendering)), I want get the notification that the rendering is complete so that I can later insert another function there. Unfortunately, I don't get an notification, I only get the warning `js: Uncaught ReferenceError: renderContext is not defined`. I just don't know from where I get the `renderContext` variable

The function I added is this:

```
def rendering_state(self):
    js_script = """
                    var page = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber;
                    //Step 1: store a refer to the renderer
                    var pageRendering = page.render(renderContext);
                    //Step : hook into the pdf render complete event
                    var completeCallback = pageRendering.internalRenderTask.callback;
                    pageRendering.internalRenderTask.callback = function (error) {
                    //Step 2: what you want to do before calling the complete method                  
                    completeCallback.call(this, error);
                    //Step 3: do some more stuff
                    alert("done");
                    };
    """
    self.page().runJavaScript(js_script)
```

I run the function on my `QWebEngineView` like this:

```
webView = MyWebView()
webView.load(QUrl.fromUserInput('%s?file=%s' % (PDFJS, PDF)))
webView.rendering_state()
```

Is it the right approach to add a class function and run, after `QWebEngineView` is initiated?